# jquery get selected element of select with optgroup is null

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

i have a select fieldwith an optiongroup on a website that will be populated by ajax.

```
<select id="wlistid" name="wlistid">
<optgroup label="My List"></optgroup>
<optgroup label="Brother List">
   <option value="5">First</option>
   <option value="8">Second</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

i use this code to load the select:

```
$('#wlistid').load('ajax.php',{'ajaxcall':'getOptions');
```

this code runs on page load.

Now i like to get the selected element of this select field. I try

```
$('select[name=wlistid]').on('change', function() {
                        var listid=$('#wlistid').children('option:selected').val();
                        alert('ID '+listid);
                    });
```

But it is still undefined.

If i remove the optgroup and change my select to:

```
<select id="wlistid" name="wlistid">
       <option value="5">First</option>
       <option value="8">Second</option>
    </select>
```

The code above works and alert the correct value.

But i like to use the optgroup. Who can help?

Comment: The php/ajax is a red-herring, ignore that

Comment: Your issue is that `<option>` is *not* ` "direct-child" of `<select>` - it's a child-child - you have `select > optgroup > option` so `.children('option:selected').length === 0` - change to `.find`

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things.

Your use of children is incorrect in this case since the options are not children of the select but of the optgroup.

Just do

```js
$('#wlistid').on('change', function() {
  var listid = this.value
  console.log('ID', listid);
  // alternatives
  console.log('ID', $(this).val());
  console.log('ID', $("option:selected",this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="wlistid" name="wlistid">
  <optgroup label="My List"></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Brother List">
    <option value="5">First</option>
    <option value="8">Second</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the use `$("select").children("option")` - this will only find "immediate-children".

As your `option` is a child of `optgroup`, your code doesn't find (any) `option`s.

In the case where you need the `<option>` and not just the `select`'s value, you can change to use `.find` to get the `option`:

```
$('#wlistid').find('option:selected');
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$('select[name=wlistid]').on('change', function() {
  var opt = $('#wlistid').find('option:selected');
  console.log(opt.val(), opt.data("details"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="wlistid" name="wlistid">
  <optgroup label="My List"></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Brother List">
    <option value="5" data-details='this one'>First</option>
    <option value="8" data-details='the other one'>Second</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```